# How to set default value of nested pydantic schema field

Tags: python, pydantic

I was trying to set the default value to the nested field of Pydantic model(generated by [`datamodel-codegen`](https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/) from below JSON data)

Using Pydantic V2

JSON data:

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 30,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "123 Main St",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY"
        },
        {
            "street": "456 Elm St",
            "city": "Los Angeles"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pydantic model:

```
from typing import List, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class AddressesItem(BaseModel):
    street: str
    city: str
    # I need this, state: Optional[str] ="NY" either getting generated by `datamodel-codegen` 
    # or overwriting this value by inheriting the final `Model`
    state: Optional[str] = None

class Model(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    addresses: List[AddressesItem]
```

How to set the default value of `state` as `NY` by inheriting the `Model`?

I was trying to do it as shown below with no luck,

```
from pydantic import field_validator

class MyModel(Model):
    class ConfigDict:
        validate_assignment = True

    @field_validator("state") # check_fields=False, even I add this, it's the same error
    def set_value(cls, state):
        return state or 'NY'
```

**Error:**

```
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: Decorators defined with incorrect fields: schema.MyModel:51085136.set_value (use check_fields=False if you're inheriting from the model and intended this
```

**Edit:**

Though I was able to find the workaround, looking for an answer using `pydantic` config or `datamodel-codegen`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Pydantic documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/). Setting `state: str ="NY"` should work

```
class AddressesItem(BaseModel):
    street: str
    city: str
    state: str ="NY"
```

Comment: This was generated by `datamodel-codegen`, I can't do it manually/directly change this. I want to inherit the final `Model` and update this to maintain consistency in code to automate other steps in the deployment pipeline process.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overwrite the field with default value as shown below by inheriting the `Model`,

```
class MyModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Overwrite the default value of the 'state' attribute
        for item in self.addresses:
            if not item.state:
                item.state= 'NY'
```

Idea here is, to set or update the default value of

```
state: Optional[str] = None
```

to

```
state: Optional[str] = 'NY'
```